# Scala implicit type conversion and ==

Tags: scala, type-conversion

Can anyone enlighten me as to why implicit type conversion does not work with `==`?

Example:

```
class BitArray(l: Int, v: Long) {  
    val length = l  
    var value = v  
    def ==(that: BitArray) = value == that.value  
    def ==(integer: Long) = value == integer  
    def +(that: BitArray) = new BitArray(length,value+that.value )  
    def +(integer: Long) = new BitArray(length,value+integer )  
//...  
}  
object BitArray{
        implicit def longToBitArray(x : Long) = new BitArray(64,x)  
        def apply(v: Long) :BitArray = apply(64,v)  
}
```

Now I can do:

```
scala> BitArray(5) + 5  
res13: BitArray = 00000000000000000000000000001010  
scala> 5 + BitArray(5)   
res14: BitArray = 00000000000000000000000000001010  
scala> BitArray(5) == 5  
res15: Boolean = true  
scala> BitArray(5) == 6  
res16: Boolean = false
```

BUT:

```
scala> 5 == BitArray(5)  
<console>:11: warning: comparing values of types Int and BitArray using `==' will   
always yield false  
       5 == BitArray(5)  
         ^  
res17: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing a fundamental aspect of Scala, which is how equality works.

Basically, all classes extending `AnyRef` implement the following method:

```
def   equals  (arg0: Any)  : Boolean
```

And all classes implement the following method:

```
def   ==  (arg0: Any)  : Boolean
```

Now, you should override not `==`, but `equals`. The method `==` will call `equals`, but Java code will use `equals`, not `==`. This is not the cause of the problem you see, but it is important enough that I think it is worth mentioning.

Now, as to the implicit not working, remember that implicits are only looked for if there is no method that satisfy your code. However, `Int`'s `==` can be compared with `BitArray`, as `==` receives an argument of type `Any`. Therefore, `Int`'s equality method is called, and no implicit is looked for.

Comment: Not so much a fundamental aspect of Scala, but an aspect of how the standard library is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @Apocalisp I meant fundamental as in "you must know this if you want to use Scala".

Answer (score 6):

To override the `==` operator, you should actually override the `equals` method:

```
override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
  case ba: BitArray => value == ba.value
  case _ => false
}
```

You can't make an instance of your `BitArray` equal to a `Long` and still obey the equals contract (ie. it won't be symmetric).

Comment: Can you elaborate? Or point me ind the direction of some documentation of how equals works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, remember that the equals function has to be SYMMETRIC, that is `(a equals b) == (b equals a)`.